# Включение части результата в следующий результат

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

строка: `abcd`, вывести `ab` `bc` `cd`. можно ли это сделать в одной регулярке, без `replace`?

p.s условие будет куда сложнее, чем вывести последний символ предыдущего результата

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сам по себе движок регексов в C# выдает непересекающиеся совпадения, но можно использовать positive lookahead:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("abcd", "(.)(?=(.))")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Точки заменить на соответствующие regex-ы для перекрываемых / неперекрываемых частей.

Стоит заметить, что простое решение с циклом и вызвов перегрузки Match с указанием начального индекса будет проще, читабельнее и эффективнее на длинных строчках.